# File.list() in Java project works in Eclipse but not from terminal

Tags: java, linux, terminal

I'm taking some files from different folders in Java as below:

```
    File d=new File(path); // Path here is surely not null
    String s[]=d.list(); 
    System.out.println("Directory: "+path+s[0]+"/");
```

Above code works in Eclipse and my OS is Ubuntu 14.04. When I compile and run the project from terminal, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at io.ReadFile.read2Dir(ReadFile.java:97)
at io.ReadFile.readDir(ReadFile.java:134)
at gui.Run.readFile(Run.java:35)
at gui.Run.main(Run.java:304)
```

Even if s[0] corresponds to a folder, I get NullPointerException in terminal.

This is how I compile from terminal:

`javac -sourcepath src -cp /home/myUsername/workspace/tezoz_my/ -encoding ISO-8859-1 src/gui/Run.java`

By the way, I had to change encoding because project is created with ISO 8859-1.

Then I run the project: 
`java gui.Run`

This is where the error occurs: 
`System.out.println("Directory: "+path+s[0]+"/");`

Thanks.

Comment: have u debug the application ??

Comment: Can you show us, how you start it from terminal?

Comment: Which line is `ReadFile.java:97` ?

Comment: @StephenC its a `java.io.ReadFile` man. there must be a problem with `path` variable. okk

Comment: @kerem I think Your path variable doesn't contains valid URL Location. this is the only reason behind this..

Comment: @VikrantKashyap - You misread my comment.  What **>>LINE<<** ?  And no, your diagnosis is not correct.  If path contained a URL then the code would not work at all.  `new File(String)` requires a pathname not a URL.

Comment: [Use JSR 203 instead](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks#Listing_files_in_a_directory.2C_oh_my)

Comment: There is no way for the line `File d=new File(path)` to throw a NullPointerException. Even if `path` is null, the exception would be thrown by a line inside the `File` constructor, not by the line given. Ergo, the NPE is not in the first line shown, which is why @StephenC was asking what's in line 97 of file `ReadFile.java`. The NPE may be from line 3, if the `path` is invalid, because that makes `list()` return null, and `s[0]` in line 3 will throw NPE.

Comment: @fge So which part exactly am I wrong about?

Answer (score 2):

If the exception occurs on one of the three lines shown, then I suspect that the problem occurs on this line:

```
   System.out.println("Directory: "+path+s[0]+"/");
```

because `s` is `null`.

The javadoc for `File.list()` says:

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

So, I surmise that this is happening because `path` contains a pathname<sup>1</sup> that either resolves to a file (not a directory), to a directory that cannot be read, or to nothing at all.  (There are other, more obscure possibilities too)

---

<sup>1 - If you did mistakenly try to use a URL, the code would attempt to resolve it as if it was a pathname.  For example "http://example.com/index.html" would refer to something in a directory whose name is "http:" which is highly unlikely to exist.  (Colon is a legal character in a filename on most modern operating systems ... though apparently not on Mac OSX.)</sup>

Comment: I finally found what's the problem. In order to get the current directory,  I was using `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. The silly mistake is I run the project in `/src` directory from the terminal. But my file is in the root directory of the project. Took the file in src folder and it worked.